# Find matching text in consecutive lines and increment numeric value in the following line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a string(Name2) in a file and match the version(*abc-xyz-0-197) in the next line and update the ID line with an incremented value.

How can this be done?

The file looks like this:

```
  Name1:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-197
    ID: 1
    primary_data: 
    somedata:
      

  Name2:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-196
    ID: 3
    primary_data: 
    somedata:

  Name3:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-192
    ID: 6
    primary_data: 
    somedata:
```

Output has to be: (for Name2 & version: *abc-xyz-0-196)

```
  Name1:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-197
    ID: 1
    primary_data: 
    somedata:
      

  Name2:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-196
    ID: **4**
    primary_data: 
    somedata:

  Name3:
    version: *abc-xyz-0-192
    ID: 6
    primary_data: 
    somedata:
```

Comment: Use a yaml parser, text-processing tools could fail when parsing yaml like text.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and set `RS=` to empty string to enable paragraph mode processing on input file:

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '$1 ~ /^ *Name2:$/ && $2 ~ /^ *version: \*abc-xyz-0-196$/ {
    bakline=$0; sub(/.*ID:/,""); newId=$0+1; 
    $0=bakline"\n"; sub(/ID: [0-9]+/,"ID: " newId);
}1' infile
```

checking the first and second line to match as what we want; backup from matched block, remove everything up to `ID:` and increment the rest of strings in force numerical, return back the block from backup variable, then replace ID with newId value.

Comment: Can i update the file inplace ?

Comment: @ranjithjn no tool (sed, perl, ruby, whatever) **really** updates the file "inplace", they all use a temp file behind the scenes so there's really no benefit to doing "inplace" editing vs just writing `tmp=$(mktemp); tool 'script' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file` for any given tool. Having said that, GNU awk has `-i inplace` to do "inplace" editing just like perl and GNU sed have `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the range operator `,` here to select the desired data point and then make changes.

```
awk '$1=="Name2:",(!NF) {
  if ($2=="*abc-xyz-0-196") f++
  if ($1 == "ID:" && f) sub(/[0-9]+/, $2+1)
  if (!NF) f=0
}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -00pe 's/Name2:\s*version: \*abc-xyz-0-196\s*ID: \K(\d+)/$1+1/e' ex
```

Where:

- `perl -00pe ...` --> for each input paragraph do `...` and print
- `s/.../exp/e` --> substitute `...` by the result of `eval exp`
- `/...1\K...2/`--> take `...1` as left context, bus substitute just `...2`